# JQuery: Dropdown Value is Not Changed using .val() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I encounter a very strange issue here.

I have two select fields that will output show same result if one of them changes selected value.

Here's the code:

```
    var qlt,internalQ;

    if (jQuery("#qlt").length>0){
                qlt =       (jQuery("#qlt").val()).split(":")[0];   
                qltDesc =   (jQuery("#qlt").val()).split(":")[1]; 
            }

    if (jQuery("#internalQ").length>0){
                internalQ = (jQuery("#internalQ").val()).split(":")[0];     
                qltDesc =   (jQuery("#internalQ").val()).split(":")[1]; 
            }

    <?php if(is_single('booklets')) { ?> 
    jQuery('#qlt').change(function(){ 
        if  (qlt=="4-1")                {   jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-1:Matt 90gsm');         }
            else if(qlt=="4-2")         {   jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-2:Silk/matt 128gsm');   }
            else if(qlt=="4-3")         {   jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-3:Silk/Matt 150gsm');   }
            calculate();
        }); 

        jQuery('#internalQ').change(function(){ 
            if  (internalQ=="4-1")      {   jQuery('#qlt').val('4-1:Matt 90gsm');               }
            else if(internalQ=="4-2")   {   jQuery('#qlt').val('4-2:Silk/matt 128gsm');         }
            else if(internalQ=="4-3")   {   jQuery('#qlt').val('4-3:Silk/Matt 150gsm');         }
            calculate();
        }); 
    <?php } ?>
```

The problem is the last conditions of each JQuery.change function (`else if(internalQ=="4-3"` and `else if(qlt=="4-3")`) does not work as expected. The value will change back to the first option, NOt the third.

If my description is not clear, my current page is: `http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/products/booklets/`

The fields I'm talking about are `Cover Quality` and `Internal Quality`

**Q: Did I miss something here? Can you point it out? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Where are `qlt` and `internalQ` defined?

Comment: oh, i forgot to put them, they are instantiated in my codes sorry. Let me edit my post

Comment: @elclanrs: I edit already my post. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: What happens when you use three equals === in your Javascript to test equality instead of two equals ==?

Comment: You are statically setting `qlt` and `internalQ` to the initial value. Don't you want to set them dynamically inside your `jQuery().change(function(){});`?

Comment: @Sean: Its because I codes in more than 20 pages.

Comment: Sean may be on to something.  I also suspect some confusion going on between the javascript variables qlt/internalQ and page elements #qlt and #internalQ. The first change() jQuery says, if the contents of page element #qlt change, then change page element #internalQ based on the qlt javascript variable.  And the second ones operates vice versa.  That is counter intuitive, unless the business logic calls for it. What one normally does is update a page element to match a javascript variable, or vice versa, and those are fairly simple operations. This is spaghetti.

Comment: Don't the two change() conditions create an endless loop? If #qlt element changes, change #internalQ which triggers the onchange for #internalQ and changes #qlt, ad infinitum.  Recommend putting a bunch of console.log() statements in there for examination/debugging.

Comment: No, its just inside a .ready() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I already solved the issue. Its my bad actually.

I have a HTML code as default that i used in displaying `Cover Quality` and `Internal Quality`:

```
<tr>                                                                                 
    <td><?php echo"Cover Quality";?></td>   
    <td>
                 <select id="qlt" name="quality">
        <option value="4-1:Matt 90gsm">Matt 90gsm</option>
        <option value="4-2:Silk/matt 128gsm">Silk/Matt 128gsm</option>
        <option value="4-3:Silk/matt 150gsm">Silk/Matt 150gsm</option>
         </select></td>     
</tr>
```

And I used the `jQuery($element).val('$val')` to change the default value.

What I'm doing wrong is: in third option in 'Cover and Interal Quality`

`else if  (internalQ=="4-3") {jQuery('#qlt').val('4-3:Silk/Matt 150gsm'); }`

instead of:

`else if  (internalQ=="4-3") {jQuery('#qlt').val('4-3:Silk/matt 150gsm'); }`

The difference is the Capital "M" and Small "m" in the values.

So I changed, the third value in my jQuery Code(or you can change the HTML) so that the value will match exactly like what is in the HTML. Solved! :)

Thanks for the prompt stackoverflow pros who helped and gave some idea. Now I know whats the cause of this issue.

I will change the title so that programmers with the same problem will be directed to this post.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#qlt').change(function(){
   var qlt = jQuery(this).val().split(":")[0];
   if(qlt.length > 0){
      //do your if else here
   }
)};
```

Do the same for #internalQ.

If you don't want to check the length each time, just avoid the if statment in the function

Comment: Thanks you. Its kinda the same with Sean's answer. I really appreciate your answer. The only thing qlt is needed to be global.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue stems from you setting `qlt` and `internalQ` statically outside your `jQuery().change(function(){});`

Try setting the values inside -

```
var qlt,internalQ;

jQuery('#qlt').change(function(){ 

    qlt =  (jQuery(this).val()).split(":")[0];  // set the value of qlt

    if(qlt=="4-1"){   
       jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-1:Matt 90gsm');
    }
    else if(qlt=="4-2"){
       jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-2:Silk/matt 128gsm');
    }
    else if(qlt=="4-3"){
       jQuery('#internalQ').val('4-3:Silk/Matt 150gsm');
    }
        calculate();
    }); 

jQuery('#internalQ').change(function(){

   internalQ = (jQuery(this).val()).split(":")[0]; // set the value of internalQ    

   if(internalQ=="4-1"){   
      jQuery('#qlt').val('4-1:Matt 90gsm');
   }
   else if(internalQ=="4-2"){   
      jQuery('#qlt').val('4-2:Silk/matt 128gsm');
   }
   else if(internalQ=="4-3"){
      jQuery('#qlt').val('4-3:Silk/Matt 150gsm');
   }
   calculate();
}); 
<?php } ?>
```

see this jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/zYg2P/1/

Comment: I really appreciat your answer. Thank you, I tried your answer but it seems their is confusion happening in my codes. Hmmm. How can easily find the error in my codes.

Comment: I tried also to use else in the last condition of each block. But the results are still wrong. :( I guess I need to spend more time searching the error in my codes

Comment: the js you posted in your question is not the js that is in your page. Take a look at this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ttd6d/ . I copied your source code from http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/products/booklets/ , and using that js does not do what it does on your page. Something else is off/missing. Which `<script>` link in your page is your js code?

Comment: the $( document ).ready() and the calculate() function which includes lots of operations. ;

Comment: well your script above always sets the other select to the 1st value. Where your live script works for the 1st 2 options, but not the last. So you must have another script somewhere that is doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I figured it out already. The error is in the HTML side